# advertisement and scan response data in BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, advertisement-server

Is it possible to set only scan response data without setting adv data in AD packets during advertisement in LE?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, this is possible. You may have 0 AD bytes in advertisement packet, and non-0 AD bytes in scan response. It makes no interest though, as it delays discovery of your device.

Note some AD types are only allowed in advertisement packet (they are forbidden in scan response -- see [CCS](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=302735) for definitions).